# Protecting questions why isn't it possible?

Tags: bug, privileges, protected-questions

I have lately got the privilege of protecting questions on Islam SE.
Maybe I don't really know how this works, but i wonder, why on some questions i would get this opportunity as it is clearly displayed, while on other questions it isn't displayed at all:

For example [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32791/was-the-injeel-ever-written-in-book-form) I can't even see the option to protect, even if the post is older than 24h.
[image]

While if i would like to protect [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32921/muslim-women-marrying-non-muslim-men-when-the-couple-are-incapable-of-producing) post. I could easily do so as the option is displayed. [image]

I'd be glad if you could tell me whether this is a bug or not and why sometimes the "Button" appears and sometimes not.

Comment: Do you understand **why** you would need to protect a question? That is, can you tell me the purpose of protecting?

Comment: Can you also tell me what isn't clear in the [help center article about the protect questions privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)?

Comment: There was a recent change, which is explained in the answer I linked to.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Oded's point was that you did not read the article in help center, as it clearly says "provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation".

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see I was just wondering as it didn't fit other posts i found here.

Comment: Since it's a recent change, all the old posts are now outdated. You can suggest edits where relevant, or new updated answers, etc.